# dominated strategy can never be used in mixed strategy nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

dominated strategy can never be used in mixed strategy nash equilibrium. how to prove it? Sounds like obvious, but how to write the proof mathematically correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition to show the expected payoff of the strictly dominated strategy is lower than the expected payoff of the strategy that dominates it for any mixed strategy of the other players.